# Ionic 2 in-app-purchase for iOS decode the Base64 recceipt

Tags: ios, ionic2, in-app-purchase, base64, receipt-validation

How can I do this? the pluging simly refers to some serve side code to do this. How do I this in Ionic 2 app?
thanks

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?